How to connect volumes running in docker for Owncloud to the host's vm folders?
I am trying to configure Owncloud in docker. The docker-compose yaml I am using look like this:
services:
  owncloud:
    image: owncloud/server:10.15
    container_name: owncloud_server
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8084:8080"
    depends_on:
      - mariadb
      - redis
    environment:
      - OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN=https://owncloud.example.com
      - OWNCLOUD_TRUSTED_DOMAINS=owncloud.example.com
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_TYPE=mysql
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_NAME=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_USERNAME=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_HOST=mariadb
      - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
      - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
      - OWNCLOUD_MYSQL_UTF8MB4=true
      - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_ENABLED=true
      - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_HOST=redis
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/oci-owncloud-config:/var/www/config
      - /home/ubuntu/oci-owncloud-data:/mnt/data

  mariadb:
    image: mariadb:10.11
    container_name: owncloud_mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - MYSQL_USER=owncloud
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=owncloud
      - MARIADB_AUTO_UPGRADE=1
    command: ["--max-allowed-packet=128M", "--innodb-log-file-size=64M"]
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-u", "root", "--password=owncloud"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/oci-owncloud-db:/var/lib/mysql

  redis:
    image: redis:6
    container_name: owncloud_redis
    restart: always
    command: ["--databases", "1"]
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - /home/ubuntu/oci-owncloud-redis:/data

When I run it, I get three containers (redis, mariadb, and owncloud). The folders in the host vm are connected to my OCI Object Storage with s3fs. The issue is on the folder user and permissions. What users and permissions should I use with Owncloud in order to connect them to my host vm's folders?
I tried:
sudo chown -R root:root /home/ubuntu/oci-owncloud-(name)
sudo chmod -R 755 /home/ubuntu/oci-owncloud-(name)

but it doesn't work.
